# How to change color of tcxgrid row

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to show some rows from tcxgrid in different color (Depend upon column value ).

I did changes for it but its not getting reflected on grid after running my project.

```
procedure TfrmMessaging.cxGrid1DBTableView1CustomDrawCell(..);
Var
  i : Integer;
begin
  For i := 0 To cxGrid1DBTableView1.ViewData.RowCount - 1 Do
  Begin
    If cxGrid1DBTableView1.ViewData.Rows[i].Values[4] = '1' Then
    Begin
      cxGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;          
    End;
  End;
end;
```

In above code I have used cxGrid1DBTableView1CustomDrawCell event of tcxgrid.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't find an answer to this in the DevExpress forums that are dedicated to their components?

Comment: I copied and pasted your question into Google and the very first suggestion was a possible answer to your question.  Please put a little more effort into your research.  We're willing to help but include search engines in your quest for an answer, too.

Comment: @SilentD, FWIW: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers ;-)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a `data-aware view` (as it seems) you need to use the `DataController` instead of the `ViewData` to get to the records.

As stated in DevExpress help for `TcxGridDBTableView` (bold format is mine):

> The TcxGridDBTableView object represents the data-aware version of the grid Table View. It inherits all functionality from its ancestor, **except for data binding settings**. The DataController.DataSource property of the TcxGridDBTableView provides the connection between the View and a TDataSet or its descendant.

Besides that, the `OnCustomDrawCell` event fires for every cell, so you do not need to iterate the rows.

Following code should help you:

```
procedure TfrmMessaging.cxGrid1DBTableView1CustomDrawCell(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  if Sender.DataController.GetValue(AViewInfo.GridRecord.RecordIndex, 4) = '1' then
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
end;
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider accepting the answer if you feel it is the solution for you. On the other hand, I also would suggest you to consider @UliGerhardt's solution as an alternative. While both solutions work, his is more flexible than mine.

Answer (score 6):

Normally the easiest path for stuff like that are cxStyles. Drop a style repository on the form, add one or more styles to it and assign them in the object inspector or in an event handler (OnGetContentStyle etc.).

One advantage over custom drawing is that styles are considered for various calculations  while owner drawn cells aren't handled specially and sometimes aren't autosized correctly etc.

Comment: Styles are perfect for this. And you have the flexibility to use them on rows or individual cells.

Comment: Styles are not usefull here, since you can give anything a style except the focused row. It is a good idea, but when not all possibilies are covered with styles, you have to fall back yet again on coding in the custom draw events. Sadly

Answer (score 2):

How I change the color of the grid

```
procedure TfrmNewOffer.GrdOffDetailViewRemarkCustomDrawCell(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
var
  backgroundColorCode: Variant;
  textColorCode: Variant;
begin
  inherited;
  if assigned(AViewInfo) and assigned(AViewInfo.GridRecord) then
  begin
    backgroundColorCode := AViewInfo.GridRecord.Values[GrdOffDetailViewBackColorCode.Index];
    textColorCode := AViewInfo.GridRecord.Values[GrdOffDetailViewTextColorCode.Index];

   if not VarIsNull(backgroundColorCode) then
   begin
     ACanvas.Brush.Color := backgroundColorCode;
   end;

   if not VarIsNull(textColorCode) then
   begin
     ACanvas.Font.Color := textColorCode;
   end;
 end;
```

end;