# Why DevExpress TCxGrid AViewInfo.EditViewInfo.Paint(ACanvas); neglects assigned font color?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I want to format DevExpress `TcxGrid (DBTableView)` in such manner that selected special cells contain blue text and the top border in red color. I have arrived at the following code:

```
procedure TTestFrame.ClipsGridCClipsViewCustomDrawCell(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
var TmpBounds: TRect;
begin
  if IsSpecialCell(...) then begin
    ACanvas.Font.Color:=clBlue;
    AViewInfo.EditViewInfo.Paint(ACanvas);
    TmpBounds:=AViewInfo.Bounds;
    TmpBounds.Bottom:=TmpBounds.Top+2;
    ACanvas.FillRect(TmpBounds, clRed);
    ADone:=True;    
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately this code neglects the blue font color and draws the cell in default formatting and only adds red top border. I guess that my problem would be solved if `AViewInfo.EditViewInfo.Paint(ACanvas);` had taken into account the assigned color. Unfortunately, this procedure uses default formatting.

So - how to solve my problem? And, generally, is it possible to draw some content in `OnCustomDraw` (e.g. inner border of the cell with `FillRec`) and to draw some other content in default drawing procedure (e.g. usual content of the cell)? At present it seems to me that I have to take choice - whether to draw everything in `OnCustomDrawCell` or let Grid draws everything and I can make only small configuration of some drawing parameters (font color, brush color) in `OnCustomDrawCell`.

Comment: What do Devex Tech support say about this?

Comment: Try `AViewInfo.Params.TextColor := clBlue`, does this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately assignment of TextColor did nothing.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22816650/2292722) to another question gives you inspiration?

Answer (score 0):

For access to private function

```
TcxPainterAccess = class(TcxGridTableDataCellPainter);

procedure TTestFrame.ClipsGridCClipsViewCustomDrawCell(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
var APainter  : TcxPainterAccess ;
begin
  APainter := TcxPainterAccess(TcxViewInfoAcess(AViewInfo).GetPainterClass.Create(ACanvas, AViewInfo));
try
  with Apainter do          
     DrawContent;
     DrawBorders;
     your code....
  finally
     Adone := True;
     Free;
  end;
end;
```